# Regular expression negative lookbehind python

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string by commas that are not inside brackets (i.e the string contains items that are separated by commas, but it also contains commas within brackets that I don't want to separate on). Like so:

```
A='[1, "A"], [2, "B"], [3, "C"], [4, "D"], [5, "E"], [6, "F"], [7, "G"], [8, "H"], [9, "I"], [10, "J"], [100, "JJ"]'
```

Which should result in:

```
['[1, "A"]', ' [2, "B"]', ' [3, "C"]', ' [4, "D"]', ' [5, "E"]', ' [6, "F"]', ' [7, "G"]', ' [8, "H"]', ' [9, "I"]', ' [10, "J"]', '[100, "JJ"]']
```

I tried using negative lookbehind like this:

```
B=re.split(r'(?<![[][\d]),',A)
```

However, this does not work when the number within the brackets goes above one digit such as in the case of [10, "J"]. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use `(?<=[\]]),`?

Comment: You may work around it with `(?<!\[\d)(?<!\[\d\d)(?<!\[\d\d\d)(?<!\[\d\d\d\d),`, etc. Or use a `regex` module and use `(?<!\[\d+),`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like *"split on any comma that is preceded by a `]`"* could work. For good measure I added `\s*` to eat up the spaces before the next item.

```
import re

A = '[1, "A"], [2, "B"], [3, "C"], [4, "D"], [5, "E"], [6, "F"], [7, "G"], [8, "H"], [9, "I"], [10, "J"], [100, "JJ"]'

re.split(r"(?<=]),\s*", A)
```

gives

```
['[1, "A"]', '[2, "B"]', '[3, "C"]', '[4, "D"]', '[5, "E"]', '[6, "F"]', '[7, "G"]', '[8, "H"]', '[9, "I"]', '[10, "J"]', '[100, "JJ"]']
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. I seem to have had the wrong approach on this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
A='[1, "A"], [2, "B"], [3, "C"], [4, "D"], [5, "E"], [6, "F"], [7, "G"], [8, "H"], [9, "I"], [10, "J"], [100, "JJ"]'
import re
data = re.split('(?<=\]),\s', A)
```

Output:

```
['[1, "A"]', '[2, "B"]', '[3, "C"]', '[4, "D"]', '[5, "E"]', '[6, "F"]', '[7, "G"]', '[8, "H"]', '[9, "I"]', '[10, "J"]', '[100, "JJ"]']
```

Comment: It's not necessary to escape a ] that is not preceded by [. (Just saying.)

Answer (score 0):

If using `split` is not a requirement, `findall` can also be used in with a very simple expression,

```
In [27]: re.findall(r'\[.+?\]', A)
Out[27]:
['[1, "A"]', '[2, "B"]', '[3, "C"]', '[4, "D"]', '[5, "E"]', '[6, "F"]', '[7, "G"]', '[8, "H"]', '[9, "I"]', '[10, "J"]', '[100, "JJ"]']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex a get each item by group 1:

`(\[\d+,\s*\"\w+\"\])`

You can see the result in this link:

https://regex101.com/r/K5XV6F/1

Answer (score 0):

Using the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) you can use

```
\[[^][]*\](*SKIP)(*FAIL) # discard anything in square brackets
|                        # or
,\s*                     # match , and whitespaces, eventually
```

---

In `Python` this looks like

```
import regex as re

A='[1, "A"], [2, "B"], [3, "C"], [4, "D"], [5, "E"], [6, "F"], [7, "G"], [8, "H"], [9, "I"], [10, "J"], [100, "JJ"]'

rx = re.compile(r'\[[^][]*\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,\s*')

print(rx.split(A))
# ['[1, "A"]', '[2, "B"]', '[3, "C"]', '[4, "D"]', '[5, "E"]', '[6, "F"]', '[7, "G"]', '[8, "H"]', '[9, "I"]', '[10, "J"]', '[100, "JJ"]']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/a7X5kk/1).